# RN app can't connect to development server, browser can

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to update from react-native 0.55.4 to react-native 0.58.4.

The issue I'm facing is that my app cannot connect to the metro bundler.
Despite adb reverse, the emulator as well as a physical device cannot connect to it.
I can open the URL just fine in the chrome browser of the device, but the app can't connect to it.

I have followed the update notices in the changelogs, resulting in the following package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

I have left out the unimportant packages.

I have also changed the .babelrc file to:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Environment info:

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz
      Memory: 3.21 GB / 15.93 GB
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.7.0 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.1.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.3.0.0 AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just updating the `package.json` is not enough when it comes to upgrading a `react-native` application. There are other changes to other files that must be made before the upgrade process is complete.

A good place to start is to look at the differences between the code in `0.55.4` and `0.58.4`. You can find these changes by looking at the git diff on `rn-diff-purge`. If you look at the following link you will see that there are a lot more changes than just the ones in the `package.json`.

https://github.com/pvinis/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.55.4...version/0.58.4

Some of these changes will be superfluous and may not actually affect the running on the application, other changes will be critical and must be done. Unfortunately the git diff doesn't tell us which we must do and which we can miss out it just tells us the differences. My advice would be to make all the changes that it suggests.

It can also be beneficial to look at vanilla versions of the app that you are starting from and then moving to. You can create a react-native app at a specific version using the following code:

`react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.55.4`

If you look at the official upgrading documentation it says:

> Some upgrades require manual steps, e.g. 0.28 to 0.29, or 0.56 to
>   0.57. Be sure to check the [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases) when upgrading so that you can identify any manual changes your particular project may require.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading#manual-upgrades

So it will also be worthwhile looking at the release notes for any specific changes that you must make.

Worst case scenario, is to create a new working app using `0.58.4`, copy your javascript code across, install and link your dependencies, and go from there.

Good luck, it can be tricky but with patience you will get there.